# C# Picturebox wont show on form1.cs?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hey guys im trying to create picture boxes on form1 using a function from createMap.cs. However once i call the function no pictureboxes are being drawn on form1? What did i do wrong?

Ive also attempted to debug it and it seems fine from what i could tell..

So... Why no pictureboxes?

form1.cs:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        createMap CreateMap = new createMap();
        CreateMap.renderMap();

    }

    public void createTile(int x, int y, int tile)
    {
        PictureBox tempTile = new PictureBox();
        tempTile.Location = new Point(20, 40);
        tempTile.Image = Resources.stone;
        Controls.Add(tempTile);
    }
```

createMap.cs:

```
public void renderMap()
    {
        int[,] mapArray = new int[10,10]{
            {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
            {2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2},
            {2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2},
            {2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2},
            {2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2},
            {2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2},
            {2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2},
            {2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2},
            {2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2},
            {2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2},
        };

        Form1 canvas = new Form1();

        MessageBox.Show(mapArray.GetLength(0) + ":" + mapArray.GetLength(1));
        MessageBox.Show(mapArray[1, 1] + ":" + mapArray[2, 2]);

        for(int x = 0; x < mapArray.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < mapArray.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("X:" + x + " Y: " + y + " Tile: " + mapArray[x,y]);


                if (mapArray[x, y] == 1)
                {
                    canvas.createTile(0, 0, 1);
                    PictureBox tile = new PictureBox();
                    tile.Location = new Point(20, 20);
                    tile.Image = Resources.dirt;
                    canvas.Controls.Add(tile);
                }

                if (mapArray[x, y] == 2)
                {
                    canvas.createTile(0, 0, 2);
                    PictureBox tile = new PictureBox();
                    tile.Location = new Point(20, 40);
                    tile.Image = Resources.stone;
                    canvas.Controls.Add(tile);



                }

                canvas.Update();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening in your code is actually it keeps on creating New Form1
Because in your code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    createMap CreateMap = new createMap();
    CreateMap.renderMap(); //in this part you call the method from the  class CreateMap
}
```

In your method `RenderMap()`, you have this code

```
Form1 canvas = new Form1();
```

which keeps on loading a new Form1.

Comment: I moved it out of the function and it still doesnt display an image? Or do i have to pass form1 to createmap with a constructor or something?

Comment: @user3585434
Sorry i wasn't able to respond to your comment, but I'm glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

First in your createMap Class. Remove the Form1 canvas = new Form1();
Replace your code with this.

```
class createMap
{

    PictureBox tile = new PictureBox();    
    public PictureBox renderMap()
    {
        int[,] mapArray = new int[10, 10]{
        {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
        {2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2},
        {2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2},
        {2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2},
        {2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2},
        {2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2},
        {2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2},
        {2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2},
        {2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2},
        {2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2},
    };



        MessageBox.Show(mapArray.GetLength(0) + ":" + mapArray.GetLength(1));
        MessageBox.Show(mapArray[1, 1] + ":" + mapArray[2, 2]);

        for (int x = 0; x < mapArray.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mapArray.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("X:" + x + " Y: " + y + " Tile: " + mapArray[x, y]);


                if (mapArray[x, y] == 1)
                {
                   // canvas.createTile(0, 0, 1);                        
                    tile.Location = new Point(20, 20);
                    tile.Image = Resources.dirt;
                   // canvas.Controls.Add(tile);
                }

                if (mapArray[x, y] == 2)
                {
                   // canvas.createTile(0, 0, 2);                                     
                    tile.Location = new Point(20, 40);
                    tile.Image = Resources.stone;
                  //  canvas.Controls.Add(tile);



                }

               //canvas.Update();

            }
        }
        return tile;
    }


}
```

And on your Form1_Load Event Change to this.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       createMap CreateMap = new createMap();
       this.Controls.Add( CreateMap.renderMap());

    }
```

In this. instead of using Update on the Form i just return tile (which is a picturebox) and adds it to the form1 controls on load event. Hope it helps